# gdalwarp changing NoDataValue in output

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I am using gdalwarp to reproject a .tif file to the same crs as a shapefile I want to clip the raster by later on.
When doing gdalwarp using

```
NDVI = gdal.Open("NDVI_2019.tif")
NDVI_rep = gdal.Warp("NDVI_repr.tif",NDVI,dstSRS = crs)
```

where crs is the crs of my Shapefile, the following output (right) is created out of the left image.

[image]

As you can see there is this "fill" to get a rectangle, where every value is just 0.

Is there a way to change the values around my actual tif to something like -1000 to filter it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`srcNodata` and `dstNodata` are the options you need. The former is the no data value of the source (say -1000 or whatever it is), and the second should be set to -1000 too if you want to keep that way.

```py
NODATA_VALUE = -1000
NDVI = gdal.Open("NDVI_2019.tif")
NDVI_rep = gdal.Warp("NDVI_repr.tif", NDVI,
                     dstSRS = crs,
                     srcNodata = NODATA_VALUE,
                     dstNodata = NODATA_VALUE)
```